# Minimum Value evenly divisible by all integers from 1 to n

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I have just started learning python and I am solving Project Euler problems alongside for practice. This is my solution for problem 5. Project Euler asks for the minimum value divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20 but I have made the program so it works from 1 to n.

I think there is a lot of room for improvement in it and I need your suggestions. Please tell me how I can improve it.

```
def least(x):
    """
    Variables:
    x = Argument of function and the maximum value of range.
    n = Number that is going to be tested by loops in each cycle.
    a = Number that is going to be added to "n" in each cycle of loop. It is initialized with "x".
        For example: if we check for all numbers from 1 to 10, each "n" has to be multiple of 10. So that's why
        a will be added to n in each turn.
    y = To minimize machine time, I have tried to bring argument of "least" function below 10.
        So if x is bigger than 10, y will be x - 10. And then we will do recursion and use "least" on y.

        For example: If we check from 1 to 40.
            least(40) -> n = least(30) = a                          (calls least(30) to get n and a)
                least(30) -> n = least(20) = a                      (calls least(20) to get n and a)
                    least(20) -> n = least(10) = a                  (calls least(10) to get n and a)
                        least(10) -> n = 10, a =10, (Brute Check)
                            (Brute Check)
        (At each stage "for loop" checks "n" in each loop cycle and adds "a" until value found.)
    """
    if x <= 10:
        n = x #The first number to test
        a = x #a is number that's going to be added in each turn
    else:
        y = x - 10
        n = least(y) #Recursion to minimize machine load and time
        a = n
    while True:
        d = 0
        for i in range(1,x + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                d += 1 #counts if i evenly divides.
            else:
                break #Checks each n. If i doesn't evenly divide, skips loop cycle.
        if d == x: #if each "i" divides evenly, d will be equal to x and thus minimum value will be n.
            return n
        else:
            n += a #adds a(specified above)
minimumvalue = least(int(input("Minimum Value divisible by all integers from 1 to n.\n Specify n: ")))
print(" Minimum Value: " + str(minimumvalue))
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/WaqasAliAbbasi/projecteuler/blob/master/Solutions/Problem%205.py)

Comment: The github link doesn''t work (anymore ?)

Comment: I am very sorry. I reorganized the solutions into another folder making this link invalid. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be more pythonic.

1. Names of variables and functions should be more meaningful and descriptive. Also - read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. You should encapsulate your code in smaller functions responsible
   for one thing. And signal what is the purpose of each function by
   it's name (= meaningful names).
3. Use power which python gives you. To save memory instead of `range()` use `xrange()` in every case when you only need to iterate over. `range()` creates a list, so if you do `range(1, 99999)` it creates a list in memory with 99999 elements. In contrast `xrange()` is a sequence object that evaluates lazily.
4. There are more efficient algorithms than brute-force. But even your
   brute-force approach can be improved. With `xranege()` you don't
   need recursion any more. What is more it's wiser to iterate over
   dividers in decreasing order. Which is dead simple in python, just use `-1` as third `xrange()` parameter (step).

Take a look at this example:

```
def smallest_common_multiple(maximal_divisor):
    for number in xrange(maximal_divisor, sys.maxsize):
        if is_common_multiple(number, maximal_divisor):
            return number

def is_common_multiple(number, maximal_divisor):
    for divisor in xrange(maximal_divisor, 1, -1):
        if number % divisor != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment:

In `smallest_common_multiple()` iteration starts from `maximal_divisor` because smaller numbers doesn't make sense. `sys.maxsize` works like *to infinity*.

:-)

**Update**

As Josay points out this can be even simpler. Thanks Josay!

```
from itertools import count

def smallest_common_multiple(maximal_divisor):
    for number in count(maximal_divisor):
        if is_common_multiple(number, maximal_divisor):
            return number

def is_common_multiple(number, maximal_divisor):
    return all([number % divisor == 0 for divisor in xrange(maximal_divisor, 1, -1)])
```

Comment: Two additional comments to your code :
 - you could use https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count to count without limits
 - you could simplify your second function by using the builtin all/any .

Answer (score 3):

### Monolithic function

You should separate yuor code into smaller functions.

### Meaningful names

You have extensive comments but the names are cryptic, I would remove some of the comments and use more self describing names.

### Avoid brute force

You should always look for an alternative approach rather than brute-force. I will not spoil you the full answer but the `smallest_common_multiple` may help you...